# CSS flexbox positioning of child elements

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to fill the available space of my flexbox layout. The goal is to fill the empty space next to the first project element with project two and three while project four to six are located in a new line.

HTML:

```html
<section class="projects">
  <article>
    Project 1
  </article>
  <article>
    Project 2
  </article>
  <article>
    Project 3
  </article>
  <article>
    Project 4
  </article>
  <article>
    Project 5
  </article>
  <article>
    Project 6
  </article>
</section>
```

CSS (SCSS):

```css
.projects {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;

  article {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 50%;
    height: 10rem;
    justify-content: center; 

    &:nth-child(1) {
      background-color: #c00;
      height: 20rem;
    }

    &:nth-child(2) {
      background-color: #0c0;
    }

    &:nth-child(3) {
      background-color: #00c;
    }

    &:nth-child(4) {
      background-color: #cc0;
      flex: 1 30%;
      order: 5;
    }

    &:nth-child(5) {
      background-color: #c0c;
      flex: 1 auto;
    }

    &:nth-child(6) {
      background-color: #0cc;
      flex: 1 auto;
      order: 6;
    }
  }
}
```

I created a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKNJyq?editors=1100) about this. What I want to get is shown in [this image](https://img42.com/2OhKN).

What am I missing to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you want to make changes in your html?

Comment: @NenadVracar I would prefer not. But what do you have in mind?

Comment: You need to nest a flexbox to contain 2 & 3. That layout is not possible with base flexbox and no additional structure.

Comment: Ok @Paulie_D. I think that is what Nenad had in mind. Do you think floats are the better alternative for this than flexbox?

Comment: That depends on your requirement. Re-ordering might be harder with floats and, of course, you won't get the equal heights automatically.

Comment: That's right, of course. I thought I can avoid nesting to not have trouble with looping elements.

Comment: @Paulie_D yes, it's possible, but  some tricks are needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (tricky) posibility is to play with margins

I have added a negative margin to the first element, to allow it to overflow.

Now there are 3 rows, and the 3rd element is starting the 2nd row.

And I have added a left margin to it, to force it under the second element

```css
.projects {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.projects article {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 50%;
  height: 10rem;
  justify-content: center;
}
.projects article:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #c00;
  height: 20rem;
  margin-bottom: -10rem;  /* added  */
}
.projects article:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #0c0;
}
.projects article:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #00c;
  margin-left: 50%;   /* added */
}
.projects article:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #cc0;
  flex: 1 30%;
  order: 5;
}
.projects article:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: #c0c;
  flex: 1 auto;
}
.projects article:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: #0cc;
  flex: 1 auto;
  order: 6;
}
```

```html
<section class="projects">
  <article>
    Project 1
  </article>
  <article>
    Project 2
  </article>
  <article>
    Project 3
  </article>
  <article>
    Project 4
  </article>
  <article>
    Project 5
  </article>
  <article>
    Project 6
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: That is slick. I tried 3 levels of nested flex containers and got a big mess.